# Pandas Dataframes with the Snowflake Python Connector

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

trying to get a data query to work with Snowflake using their connector.

```
import snowflake.connector as sf
import pandas as pd
import sys

ctx = sf.connect(
    user='<user>',
    password='<password>',
    account='<account>',
    warehouse='<warehouse?',
    database='<db>',
    schema='<schema>',
    )
cs = ctx.cursor()

try:
    cs.execute('select TOP 5 fish, price from fishtable order by fish;')
except Exception as error:
    error = sys.exc_info()[0]
    message = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print(f"Error: {error}\nMessage: {message}")
finally:
    ctx.close()
    
print(cs.rowcount)
print(cs.sfqid)
df = cs.fetch_pandas_all()   #could not get this to work
df
```

print(cs.rowcount) shows the correct total of 5.

Using sfqid in snowflake console returns the query results as expected.

But no data in DF...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment should be done before closing/disposing connection:

```
try:
    cs.execute('select TOP 5 fish, price from fishtable order by fish;')
    df = cs.fetch_pandas_all() 
except Exception as error:
    error = sys.exc_info()[0]
    message = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print(f"Error: {error}\nMessage: {message}")
finally:
    ctx.close()

df
```

Comment: Your answer works...not as familiar with Python and using it in VCS...the other thing I had to do to see the data was to wrap the df with a print(df).  Thanks.